# C# infinite do while loop

Tags: c#, loops

can anyone tell me why it loop infinitely?

```
       bool rat1 = (ratswitch == 1);
       bool rat2 = (ratswitch == 2);
       bool rat3 = (ratswitch == 3);
       bool rat4 = (ratswitch == 4);
       bool rat5 = (ratswitch == 5);
       do
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Podano bledna ocene, uzyj liczb calkowitych z zakresu 1-5.");
           ratswitchstring = Console.ReadLine();
           while (ifintrat != true)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Podano bledna ocene, uzyj liczb calkowitych z zakresu 1-5.");
               ratswitchstring = Console.ReadLine();
               ifintrat = int.TryParse(ratswitchstring, out ratswitch);
           }
           ratswitch = Convert.ToInt32(ratswitchstring);
           rat1 = (ratswitch == 1);
           rat2 = (ratswitch == 2);
           rat3 = (ratswitch == 3);
           rat4 = (ratswitch == 4);
           rat5 = (ratswitch == 5);
       }
       while (rat1 == false || rat2 == false || rat3 == false || rat4 == false || rat5 == false);
```

I ran it with debugger and it switches 1 of them to true when i put 1 or 2 for example so I think problem is in while conditions. Any ideas ?

Comment: what is `ifintrat`? just a boolean variable?

Comment: ifintrat is boolean to check if it fits into int, that works for me and doesn't create loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       rat1 = (ratswitch == 1);
       rat2 = (ratswitch == 2);
       rat3 = (ratswitch == 3);
       rat4 = (ratswitch == 4);
       rat5 = (ratswitch == 5);
```

Only one of these can ever be true.

```
while (rat1 == false || rat2 == false || rat3 == false || rat4 == false || rat5 == false)
```

So at least 4 of these will be false. Maybe you need && (and) instead of || (or)?

Answer (score 0):

Your while condition will loop whenever rat1, rat2, rat3, rat4 or rat5 are false. Look at the previous 5 lines of code; one of these booleans will always be true while the others are all false.

Comment: Thanks, i misused || with &&.

Answer (score 0):

Only one of the following lines will be true, other will be false

```
       rat1 = (ratswitch == 1);
       rat2 = (ratswitch == 2);
       rat3 = (ratswitch == 3);
       rat4 = (ratswitch == 4);
       rat5 = (ratswitch == 5);
```

hence, your condition will always evaluate to true

```
  . . . 
} 
while (true || true || true || true || false) // only one condition will return false
```

to exit the loop when anyone of rat1 .... rat5 is true, you should write

```
 while (rat1 == false && rat2 == false && rat3 == false && rat4 == false && rat5 == false)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ratswitch` can't be equal with 5 values at the same time so at least 4 of the rat1,rat2,rat3,rat4,rat5 will be false and it will continue looping.
try using `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to exit the loop when one of the switches becomes true, you need to change your while condition to say:

```
while (rat1 == false && rat2 == false && rat3 == false && rat4 == false && rat5 == false)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as one of your rat values equals to false, the loop will continue to be executed.

As you have it right now, the only situation that will end it is by having ALL of your values set to true, instead of just one like you want to.

Try changing the or (`||`) with and and (`&&`) and it should execute until one of the rat values is changed to true, then it will end.